# Custom Button Image width and height in XML

Tags: android, xml

I have the following implementation, and please see following image, and in the first button (`id:button3`) does not fit into button, or button size is big for the custom image. I wonder how to fix that issue.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="48dip"
            android:layout_height="39dip"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/undo_button" />
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />
        <Button
           android:text="Button"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/button1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use andriod:background instead.

Comment: Your approach works. If you want, please provide a separate answer and then I will mark and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force your undo_button drawable to scale nicely, use an ImageButton instead.

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:id="@+id/view3"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="39dip"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:src="@drawable/undo_button"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this documentation for [android:drawableRight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableRight) and [android:background](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:background).

Here what you need to set is background: Also see selector to set clickable background.

```
android:background="@drawable/undo_button"
```